# How to remove all CR (\r) chars from a bash script file before using it in a Google Cloud Build step?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

There's a step in my `cloudbuild.yaml` file that process a bash script file within a Ubuntu image. It works well if the file is edited in Linux, but fails if it's edited in Windows, because Windows text editors usually handle EOL with CRLF, instead of LF.

```
- name: 'ubuntu'
  args: ['bash', './my-script.sh']
```

One of the commands in the script creates `my-folder`. I expect the folder to be created for every build, but it fails with below message when the script is last edited in Windows (please notice the `\r` at the EOL):

*mkdir: cannot create directory './my-folder/\r': No such file or directory*

How can I improve `cloudbuild.yaml` to get rid of this?

Comment: Do you have acces to the common utility `dos2unix`?

Comment: Using `dos2unix` maybe would help, @John1024, but I fixed it using `sed` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/57351276/7096300). Do you see any issues with my proposed solution?

Comment: `dos2unix` and `sed` can do the exact same thing.  For sed, though, you might try `sed 's/\r$//'`

Comment: `sed 's/\r$//'` works and is clearer than my initial solution, so I'm updating it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Replace the build step by:

```
- name: 'ubuntu'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args:
  - '-c' # pass what follows as a command to bash
  - |
    sed 's/\r$//' ./my-script.sh > sh
```

It uses `sed` editor to ignore all CR (\r) chars when reading the script file, then pass the content to `sh`, that will process it.

Comment: Converting would be a possibility, @SSF. But do you see any issues with this `sed` solution?

Comment: This may work. I haven't tested. That said there may be other characters that you may have to include in your `sed` statement. So I would recommend using a utility that covers all the characters.

Comment: Got it, thanks. I'll check if `dos2unix` is available in the image.

Comment: Just tested, `dos2unix` is not available: _starting container process caused "exec: \"dos2unix\": executable file not found in $PATH"_. So I'll keep the `sed` approach. Thanks.

Comment: As I said in the edit, if it is not available you can install it using `apt-get`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that this is Ansible, you can use the `shell` module to convert the file into unix format. See eaxmple below:

```
- name: Execute dos2unix on several files
  shell: dos2unix “{{ scripts_dir }}/*.sh"
  args:
    chdir: "/home/yourdir/"
```

This should convert the script into unix format. You can then execute the script as you would using Ansible.

**EDIT**
If you do not have the dos2unix utility available, you can install it using Ansible prior to executing it:

```
- name: Install dos2unix
  apt:
    name: dos2unix
    state: present
```

Comment: Would it work in Cloud Build? I've never seen a build step with such arguments...

Comment: which on? The `dos2unix` command? It should work. You can use the absolute path to your script in the `shell` step so you can get it working (i.e. substitute `{{ scripts_dir }}` with the path to the script).